# How to find given address lies in a given city in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have two fields in a table, one is city and other is address. I have to find whether address lies inside city or not. How can i find this.

## for fetching lat and lng of city

```
 $city_lat_lng =json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$ogl_city}&sensor=false"));
 $city_lat = $city_lat_lng->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
 $city_long = $city_lat_lng->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

## for fetching lat and lng of address

```
$address_lat_lng = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$ogl_address}&sensor=false"));
$address_lat = $address_lat_lng->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$address_long = $address_lat_lng->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

In the above code, we are able to find lat long of both address and city. But don't get any proper idea of how to find whether a particular address lies inside a specific city. Both city and address dynamic here. I am new in Laravel. searched on google also but not get any proper solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if Lat/Lng in Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939408/determine-if-lat-lng-in-bounds)

Comment: Just check the address components in the API response

Comment: If the API only returns the centroid of the city then there's no reliable way to do this. You need to somehow get the city boundaries. Then it's just a matter of determining if a point is inside a polygon

Comment: you have any idea how to determine boundaries of a city usin api?

Answer (score 1):

You can use address_components from the API response to get the city:

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$ogl_city}&sensor=false"));
$firstOption = $response[0];

for($i=0;$i<count($firstOption['address_components']);$i++)
{
    if (in_array ("administrative_area_level_1", $firstOption['address_components'][$i]['types']))
    {
        echo "city = ". $firstOption['address_components'][$i]['long_name'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

`administrative_area_level_1` is a type of administrative area, check which types match your idea of a city here:  https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: I have a random address, and a random city . i have to find whether this address lies inside this city or not. Any idea for this. then please share.

Comment: You can search address_components for that particular city